# Ajax возвращает ответ от сервера только один раз

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Отправляю данные из html-формы на сервер простым ajax-запросом:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add_data.php",
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
      $('#success').html(data);
      $('#form')[0].reset();
      $('#success').fadeOut(4000);
    }
});
```

Сервер возвращает ответ, который появляется в #success. Но почему-то это происходит только при первой отправке данных. При второй, третьей и т.д. данные в базу успешно заносятся, однако ответ от сервера в #success не появляется.

Если перезагрузить страницу, то ответ снова один раз приходит, а потом нет.

Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: а в консоле браузера что?

Comment: @Vartlok пусто (ошибок нет)

Comment: А запросы на сервер уходят? ответ приходит?

Comment: да, разобраться бы сначала с маршрутам - всё ли ушло-пришло-вышло-зашло :-) где-то ошибка, скорей всего падает обработчик запроса на сервере, а может еще что

Comment: поставьте логирование на 4 контрольных точки (2 на клиенте и 2 на сервере) на входы и выходы и всё будет видно сразу

Comment: @EugeneBartosh ох, если б я ещё знал, как это делается (

Comment: что ж тут не знать - на клиенте - console.log(...) или alert если уж хотите, на сервере - если php - error_log(...), еще var_dump(...) оч полезна, если на сервере node.js - тоже console.log() :-)

Comment: начните хотя бы с console.log(data); в функции success

Comment: @Alexus в console.log пишется каждый раз, да. Значит, проблема с html(data)? но в чём именно?

Comment: добавьте `$('#success').show();` перед `$('#success').html(data);`

Comment: @Igor ну конечно!! спасибо ) я затупил просто: закрыл блок fadeOut'ом и чего-то хочу от него ((

Comment: @humster_spb проанализируйте значение data первый раз и последующие разы, в чем отличие может быть от сервера приходят не те данные

Comment: @Alexus чуть выше Igor уже подсказал, в чём ошибка - всё дело в $('#success').fadeOut(4000), который первый раз скрывает блок и больше этот блок не показывается, пока страница не будет загружена

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При каждом сабмите обнулите поле вывода:

```
$('#success').html('').show();
```

Comment: Ну, почти так: я просто добавил $('#success').show() перед $('#success').html(data);